# How to apply css selector in ZK

Tags: css, zk

Here are some part of my codings inside index.zul :

```
<grid>
    <columns>
        <column/>
        <column/>
    </columns>
    <rows>
        <row>
            <label value="${labels.personal.name}"/>
            <label value="@load(vm.personal.name)"/>
        </row>
        <row>
            <label value="${labels.personal.id}"/>
            <label value="@load(vm.personal.id)"/>
        </row>
    <rows>
<grid>
```

I tried to use the CSS below but somehow it bold every label inside row element.

```
.z-label:FIRST-CHILD{
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

So, how can I apply font-weight only to the first label tag for each row element ?

Comment: Which elements has the `.z-label` class? The label?

Comment: In zk we can apply style directly to the element like this one [http://zkfiddle.org/sample/1l8b5kk/1-apply-style-to-all-textbox-in-css](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/1l8b5kk/1-apply-style-to-all-textbox-in-css), but I'm not sure if it works for CSS selector

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `sclass` attribute so your css is applied with the default css.

```
<style>
    .bold{
        font-weight: bold;
    }
</style>
<grid>
    <columns>
         <column/>
         <column/>
    </columns>
    <rows>
        <row>
            <label value="${labels.personal.name}" sclass="bold"/>
            <label value="@load(vm.personal.name)"/>
        </row>
        <row>
            <label value="${labels.personal.id}" sclass="bold"/>
            <label value="@load(vm.personal.id)"/>
        </row>
    </rows>
</grid>
```

You can test it in [this fiddle.](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/16rnhtk/1-sclass-usage)

### Update:

I looked around in the DOM and played a little further with the css selectors so I came to [this solution](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/16rnhtk/3-sclass-usage)

```
.z-row-inner:first-child .z-label {
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Comment: yup, this thing works for me, but for a long script, it will be a little bit troublesome to add `sclass` to each first `label`. It will be a lot easier to use `:first-child`, but I don't know how to do that in ZK.

Comment: @Mrye there is your solution ;)

Comment: "it will be a little bit troublesome to add sclass to each first label", you should probably look into "template", see [this](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/MVVM/Syntax/Data_Binding/@template) for example

Comment: @chillworld yup its working. thanks. I have trouble with `z-row-inner`, `z-row-content` ,etc. I wonder if there's any documentation on these things.

Comment: @Mrye yes : http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Style_Customization_Guide but I prefer working with the developer tools in IE or FF and look for myself.